# How to clear/hide transaction history in PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

I am using a shared PC with my brother and I don't want him to know about my PayPal transactions. (Because I often forgot to logout before leaving the PC.) So I want to know how to clear/hide the transaction history?

p/s : Or is there a way to make them hard to see. Archive method isn't good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about your situation, one suggestion is to access PayPal in a browser that's running in private mode (e.g., Incognito - Chrome, Private Browsing - Firefox, etc.). Close your browser when you're done with whatever you're doing, and no one will be able to view your browser history even if you forget to log out.

Comment: Or in a window that was opened in Incognito/Private Browsing mode. Moreover, you don’t need to close the browser, just the respective window.

Comment: Thank you but I am asking about Paypal transaction history not browser history.

Comment: @JatSing This is clearly a workaround that does not answer your question, but it resolves your initial problem, because if you login from a private browsing window, when you close it, it automatically logs you out (kills the respective login session).

Comment: Sometimes I even forgot to close the browser. You won't believe it but I am very careless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not delete it.. But you can archive it.. Ones you archive it will be hidden.

Hope following link may help you.

https://getsatisfaction.com/paypal/topics/paypal_can_you_delete_transactions

Comment: Thank uou but that seem not to work, he still can view them in history.

Answer (score 1):

**What you are asking for is not possible, you need to implement better computer operator habits.** Please do not base the rest of this "Answer" as an Answer in regards to your question, they are just suggestions:

1. If you both use the same account on your PC than this wont work: If
   you alter the Control Panel settings for sleep mode to 1 minute.
   Then, after 1 minute of inactivity your PC will lock/logout of the
   current user's account, and will force your brother to login with the
   correct password.
2. You cannot **completely** remove your payment history in PayPal (only move it to archives),
   especially since PayPal abides by a very stringent, government mandated policy on how money
   is recorded/presented. I would suggest getting a new account.
3. You could open a page that looks exactly like PayPal's payment
   history every time you use your PC, so that when you brother logs on
   he thinks that it is initially a PayPal account, but soon realizes
   that it isn't. After about a week of this he will naturally close the
   window, and not see your activity (when the real PayPal window is open).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I ended up making a new account be the exact same in order to completely clear the history. Here's what I did: 
(You'll need to have access to the phone number and email your account is linked to)

- Note down all your account info locally (phone number, address, card information, etc) by taking a screenshot, copying it into a document, etc. Including your profile picture.
- Send all your money on your PayPal balance to a secondary account, trusted friend or to your bank account
- Change your primary email address to something else and remove your old email address
- Delete your account
- Make a new account with your real email
- Validate your phone number and email address
- Update all your info to match the one in your old PayPal (all the info you noted down) Including the profile picture, linked bank and cards.
- Get the money back from your secondary account, friend, etc.

Comment: Although it might help, it sounds that in the OP situation it's a reoccurring thing so it won't be practical